# Rails remote link modal to create and edit records

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ujs

I have followed the tutorial found [here](https://richonrails.com/articles/basic-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails)

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to allow users to edit records from the index page, using modals.

In my index.haml view I have this:

```
- @bars.each do |bar|
  = link_to "Edit", edit_bar_path(bar), remote: true, class: "btn btn-default"

#bar-modal.modal.fade
```

In _edit.haml:

```
.modal-header
  %h3= "Editing #{@bar.foo}"
= render "form"
```

In edit.js.erb

```
$("#bar-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit') %>")
$("#bar-modal").modal("show")
```

In _form.haml

```
= bootstrap_form_for @bar, remote: true do |f|  
  = f.text_field :foo
  = f.button "Save"
```

My controller is a standard rails generated CRUD controller.

For some reason, this does not display a modal if I click on the link. I got it working in a different way, but then it opened up a 'create' form rather than an edit one.

I'm using bootstrap and haml. I have made sure that there are no errors in firebug.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you post your `index.html.haml`?

Comment: @ArunKumar the first code segment in the question is currently my full index file. I removed everything else to try and get it working

Comment: added a solution. Let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Did you modfiy the controller to render `js` reponse?

In the `edit` action of your controller, add

```
def edit
  #find the record
  respond_to |format|
    format.js # this will render edit.js.haml
    # other formats
  end
end
```

And you have mixed `erb` with `haml` in your edit.js.haml. Replace that with

```
$('#modal-container').html('#{ j(render 'edit') }');
$('#bar-modal').modal("show");
```

When the first line of code is executed, `#bar-modal` exists in our document. And then you can call `modal` method on it to display the modal.

Note that `j` is an alias for `escape_javascript`. (Less keystrokes)

Make sure that you have `div` with id `modal-container` in the `index.html.haml`. And your modal(in  `_edit.html.haml`) should have an id  of `bar-modal`.

And your modal in `_form.html.haml` should look something like this:

```
.modal.fade.in#bar-modal
  .modal-dialog
     .modal-content
       .modal-header
         %h3= "Editing #{@bar.foo}"
       .modal-body
         = render "form"
```

Note that we have a modal with id `bar-modal` and this will be rendered into the placeholder div `#modal-container` which should be in `index.html.haml`. It should be something like this.

```
%div{id: "modal-container"}
  <!-- this is where the modal will go in -->

- @bars.each do |bar|
  = link_to "Edit", edit_bar_path(bar), remote: true, class: "btn btn-default"
```

Add the `modal-container` to the top of the document. From bootstrap's documentation,

> Modal markup placement
>
> Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks like something is happening now. I'm seeing a 500 error in firebug when clicking on the link. So trying to figure out why... I will let you know once solved. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I got rid of the 500 error. But the modal is still not showing. I can see in my log that it is rendering the view files I expected, but the modal is not displayed in the browser.

Comment: @Herm In the network tab, do you see the `modal html` in the response body? Do you have the project in github? If yes, post the url. I'll have a look

Comment: I only see en 'edit' line in the network tab. This is of type 'xhr'. Nothing else is there. I have the project in BitBucket, but unfortunately it's a private repo.

Comment: @Herm, are you passing in `'#{ j(render 'edit') }'` to the `html` method? I suspect there's something wrong with your `edit.js.haml`. Can you share a gist of the code you tried?

Comment: I have loaded my complete edit.js.haml file here: https://gist.github.com/HermannHH/0ed732d93ffcdf4e32268ba51418e596 . You'll notice that I used your suggestions verbatim :-)

Comment: @Herm, can you please add all the changes you made for this feature into a single gist? Actually, I asked you to post all the code but because of my second sentence, you misinterpreted.

Comment: I have added all of my code to this new gist: https://gist.github.com/HermannHH/67846e6029b4e35a808c836d93e7765e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121191/discussion-between-herm-and-arun-kumar).